# Is there any method available to automatically show the ruby when writing sentences with Japanese Kanji?

Tags: programming

I want to write a note for my study on Japanese Language with LaTeX. So far I have to write the ruby (furigana) for each Kanji manually such as `\ruby{天}{てん}`. It seems to be tedious and makes my input file no longer "natural".

What I want to have is to let the computer (LaTeX) automatically provide the ruby for every single Kanji character (if possible) or a set of Kanji characters (for compound words).

Is there any method available to automatically show the ruby when writing sentences with Japanese Kanji in LaTeX?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ruby}
\begin{document}
Is \ruby{this}{MWE} really needed? I don't think so.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example (MWE) that compiles, so that those willing to help you have something with which to work.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: There is the `luatexja-ruby` package if lualatex is a possibility, but I can't tell if that is automatic or not `texdoc latexja-ruby` is a little challenging for me to read:-)

Comment: The MWE you added is not useful, but a real example might have been, which has a real mapping from kanji to the equivalent ruby annotation (or even give a link to such a mapping if it exists in public readable form)

Comment: `luatexja-ruby` does not provide the furigana or ruby automatically, I think.

Comment: what would be needed is a resource that contains the equivalences.  i don't know of any such, but will query someone who might know.

Comment: The site http://www.furiganizer.com/ will add the ruby using html markup (nested tables not proper html ruby) but from there it wouldn't be too hard to run a translation script to generate the tex markup.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sounds cool :-)

Comment: This will be extremely difficult, especially because kanji have at least two readings. The example you gave, 天, can be read as てん、あま、or (rarely) あめ. An approach where you look up the input word in a dictionary would also encounter this problem, as some compound kanji can have multiple readings, one of which is preferred. For example, 天地 can be てんち or あめつち, the former being preferred. You would need to somehow capture the keyboard input, but for the purpose of study I would recommend sticking with your current method or, better yet, write by hand :)

Comment: This isn't exactly an ideal solution and certainly doesn't make the input file look that much cleaner, but there is an option of defining very commonly used and/or cumbersome kanji-reading pairs as global macros instead of retyping the reading every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not as easy as you may think.  For a text processor to do a reasonable job at detecting word boundaries in Japanese you need to do morphological analysis on it.  You can then look up each word in a dictionary and add the ruby for each kanji, but doing that automatically will probably introduce errors too.

Anyway, it would be a rather involved project to do that in TeX.  Any reasonable attempt would of course use existing tools.  A very quick Google search yields for example [this site](http://jprocessing.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) that offers tools in Python (what you would need here is their `jTokenize` function).  There a several other tools.  [This](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/japanesenlp/) page from Microsoft Research, about their own tools, explains the general issue of natural language processing for Japanese.

In other words: it’s practically a research-level project.