# seqsplit error: \SQSPL@scani has an extra }

Tags: line-breaking, syntax

I created some commands to allow me to easily handle Japanese text in Latex. Recently I added seqsplit to automatically break lines, as Japanese text is handled as a single word due to the lack of spaces.

However when compiling (using xelatex) I get the following error message:
`! Argument of \SQSPL@scani has an extra }.`

I can't find any extra braces though.
Here's a minimal example to reproduce the error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,13pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{seqsplit}

\setmainfont{Droid Serif}
\newfontfamily\japtext{IPAMincho}

\newcommand{\jap}[1]{{\seqsplit{\japtext #1}}}
\newcommand{\furi}[2]{$\stackrel{\mbox{\tiny #2}}{\mbox{#1}}$}

\begin{document}
\jap{\furi{テスト}{Test}}
\end{document}
```

I have 2 questions concerning this problem:

1. Is there really an extra brace in my code I just haven't noticed?
2. Is there a more suitable package to break lines automatically?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's the expected output. I doubt that `\seqsplit` is the right tool. Please note that “jap” is considered a derogatory term.

Comment: You are passing `$\stackrel{\mbox{\tiny Text}}{\mbox{テスト}}$` to `\seqsplit`. What should it do with it besides complaining loudly?

Comment: egreg: The expected output of the furi command is a small reading aid (2nd argument) above the first argument and works without seqsplit. Thanks for pointing that out. I'm not a native English speaker so I wasn't aware of that. I didn't intend to be rude in any way; I was just too lazy to type out "japanese" over and over.

Comment: Ulrike Fischer: So that means that seqsplit isn't able to handle math mode / macros?

Comment: don't you want the `ruby` package eg http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247440/is-there-any-method-available-to-automatically-show-the-ruby-when-writing-senten

Comment: @Max seqsplit can not handle macros `{}` groups or multi-byte non-ascii letters, and you have all of those.

Comment: @Max: Did you looked at least once in the documentation of the package? Beside this: You are putting the text in boxes, and boxes are unbreakable.

Comment: I really didn't read the documentation because I thought that the fact that seqsplit pointed out a _missing_ brace means that it is able to handle these and that the problem was the nesting of my own macros. Reading the documentation, I found a workaround for the problem (grouping my \furi macros), so I will consider this question solved. Thanks to everyone who commented!